# Asterisk dialplan get dynamic the technology of extension?

Tags: asterisk

I would like to ask if it is possible to retrieve dynamic the technology(etc SIP,ZAP...) of extension inside on dialplan script? I need some guide where to look.

Thanks for your attention and time!

Comment: I have try this:`
${DB(devices/${EXTEN}/dial)}
`
 but nothing is return

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manage to create php, to get the information a need from the asterisk db, then call the curl application inside the dialplan and now I can retrieve the technology of the extension dynamic.